# UISearchBar acting like a UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar` implemented into my `UITableViewController`, my problem is when I scroll down in my table view, the search bar acts like a cell and scrolls with the table, therefore disappearing. Is there a war to programmatically fix this?

I know there are similar questions on SO with this issue and I have exhausted all the resources provided in those posts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, don't use an `UITableViewController` but use a normal `UIViewController` with `UITableView` and `UISearchBar` inside.

When you use an `UITableViewController`, its `UIView` is directly the `UITableView`. So every control and subview go in the `tableView`. For this reason you need to change strategy and use the way above.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, that would require me redoing all 9 of my views. Which stinks

Comment: I rarely use a TVC.  Static TableViews are about the only time I don't use a regular VC and add in a TableView.  You get lots more freedom when do it that way.

Comment: Answer improved: When you use an `UITableViewController`, its `UIView` is directly the `UITableView`. So every control and subview go in the `tableView`. For this reason you need to change strategy and use the way above.